# Singlestore (memsql) query causing High CPU usage and locks on the table

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, database-performance, singlestore

High CPU usage and locks on the table are being caused by my query.
Performance has not improved despite my attempts with various cluster indexes and shard keys.

In Memsql we have created this table and performing this query. In my environment, this query is the top slow running query. Please advice on how to optimise this Memsql table or query.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mobile_flow` (
  `marker` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `teqthry` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `stry_on` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `stry_clsd` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `matr_start` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `cost_no` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `prc_findr` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost_row` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `prd_sol` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `prd_range` double NOT NULL,
  `prd_invty` double NOT NULL,
  `prd_hagx` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_n1` (`marker`,`teqthry`,`matr_start`) USING HASH,
  KEY `index_1` (marker`,`teqthry`,`matr_start`) USING CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE,
  SHARD KEY `shd_n1` (`matr_start`,`teqthry`)
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM mobile_flow
WHERE matr_start<1426393500 and matr_start>=1525202400 AND teqthry='kund' AND marker in ('scpopec', 'rdeg', 'dhendqs');
```

Comment: Is this actually related to Microsoft SQL Server (the `sql-server` tag)? Seems like MySQL.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: And there is nothing we can tell you about performance from that. We need the execution plan.

Comment: it is related memsql-singlestore

Comment: to tag memqsl i need minimum of 1500 reputation and memsql is flavour of mysql only

Comment: Well you can be sure its not related to SQL Server, so please remove that tag.

Comment: removed sql tag

Comment: Memsql is called [tag:singlestore] now. Tag added.

Answer (score 0):

Are the columns you use in the filter indexes? If not try to make as many indexes as possible from the columns used in filter.

You can try rearranging the filter order, keep the filter which removes the most number of rows first followed by next biggest filter. This will make sure that downstream filters need not work on large number of records. In Case you are unable to make all those columns as indexes, keep the biggest indexed column filter at the top followed by others.

Answer (score 0):

For your query you want a BTREE-like index on `(marker, teqthry, matr_start)`. That matches your query pattern, which searches for equality on the first two columns and a range-scan on the third. The Singlestore people have a BTREE-like structure called a skiplist, declared by calling it  BTREE.

You already have that index, but it's a clustered column key which doesn't have the same query plan characteristics as the Skiplist.

I don't have access to a singlestore system or to your data. And, I'm no expert on it so I can't try this out. But you might try something like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mobile_flow
 DROP KEY index_1
  ADD KEY index_1 (marker, teqthry, matr_start) USING BTREE;
```

If I were you I'd ask Singlestore support for a bit of help if this doesn't work.

Comment: i have tried by creating Btree index on (marker, teqthry, matr_start) but not seen any performance improvement, please suggest in case of any more suggessions.

Comment: Please ask another question about your problem. To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) before you ask your question.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat:  The following is advice for MySQL; it may or may not apply for "memsql".

For MySQL, `IN` with multiple options does not optimize as well as `=`.

Add these two 'composite' (and 'covering') indexes; the Optimizer will pick which one is better:

```
INDEX(teqthry, marker, matr_start)
INDEX(teqthry, matr_start, marker)
```

Check it with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; that will say "Using index" if it is 'covering'.

If this is a huge table, see can also discuss [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: created indexes on (teqthry, marker, matr_start),(teqthry, matr_start, marker) both seperately and tested but not observed any improvement.

Comment: Can you provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`